# Bloomberg Intraday Historical Speed Up

Tags: python, bloomberg

I am using the python API to download intraday data (5min bars) for a number of securities.
But that process is painfully slow, and I imagine I am not making the best effort in terms of concurrent requests.

Unfortunately, I find the `API` to be quite unfriendly (I use mostly the `blpapi` wrapper to get around the messaging, though I'm keen to play with the bloomberg api directly if need be).

I'd be glad if anyone would have an example as for how to tweak my requests to make it less time consuming

Comment: is it one big request or many smaller ones? if the latter, you could use the basic multithreading functionality of Python to fire those requests in parallel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to diagnose performance issues without some idea of how you are
structuring your requests, but I imagine most of the time is spent waiting for
Bloomberg responses. You might want to take a look at the
`CorrelationID` field. This allows you to send out multiple requests prior to
parsing the responses and then have a way to identify the which response
messages correspond to which requests.

Take a look at page 58 of the [Developer's Guide](https://data.bloomberglp.com/professional/sites/10/2017/03/BLPAPI-Core-Developer-Guide.pdf) to give you some idea.

In python the code looks like

```
cid = blpapi.CorrelationId(my_unique_identifier)
session.sendRequest(request, correlationId=cid)
```

Comment: Thanks I thought there might be one easier way to get that but I feel I need to get my hands dirty. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It takes most time for you to make connection to Bloomberg rather than the actual downloads. You can save your connection object and use it repeatedly.

This package [`xbbg`](https://xbbg.readthedocs.io) makes this whole process super easy:

```
from xbbg import blp

# Connection instance will be shared at the backend
blp.create_connection()

tickers = [.....]
dt = '...'
for t in tickers:
    # Every download in the loop shares the same connection
    blp.bdib(t, dt)
```