# Bloomberg/Python - Speed up IntraDayBar Request

Tags: python, bloomberg

I am trying to speed up this Bloomberg xbbg code. It's taking 60s to pull c. 8.9k rows of data; there must be a faster option? Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from xbbg import blp, pipeline

cl_chain = [
    'CL1 Comdty', 'CL2 Comdty', 'CL3 Comdty', 'CL4 Comdty', 'CL5 Comdty',
    'CL6 Comdty', 'CL7 Comdty', 'CL8 Comdty', 'CL9 Comdty', 'CL10 Comdty',
    'CL11 Comdty', 'CL12 Comdty'
]

cl_hist = pd.concat([
    pd.concat([
        blp.bdib(ticker, dt=dt, interval=60, ref='CME') for ticker in cl_chain
    ],
              axis=1) for dt in pd.bdate_range(end='today', periods=31)
],
                    sort=True)
```

Note: Answer here: [Bloomberg Intraday Historical Speed Up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47390083/bloomberg-intraday-historical-speed-up) no longer applicable as it refers to an older version of xbbg, solution didn't work for me.

Comment: Sent multiple requests in parallel will make chaos in returned values. Intraday prices from ticker A will be returned to ticker B, even though you request them in different threads. This is a Bloomberg API problem.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up splitting the requests into 12 individual requests. Reduced the time from 60s to 5s.