# Speeding up xbbg.blp requests

Tags: python, bloomberg, blpapi

I am trying to query a bunch of deal tickers using xbbg.blp.bdp
However when entering the deals as a list:

```
from xbbg import blp
blp.bdp(tickers=deal_list,flds=flds_list)
```

the return dataframe sometimes have all the tickers, but most of the time half of the tickers and some rare cases return 0 or 1 tickers. So I have to query the tickers one at a time, and that is very slow. Wondering if there is a way to speedup the process by running them in parallel.

See [Bloomberg/Python - Speed up IntraDayBar Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73109973/bloomberg-python-speed-up-intradaybar-request/73723796?noredirect=1#comment130184865_73723796) mentioning splitting the request, wondering how it is done.

Comment: Is the ticker list the same every time? Are all the tickers of the same type (eg Index, Govt etc)? If a ticker doesn't have entries for any of the fields, it will not be in the returned dataframe. Check the 'missing' ones in the Terminal and see if they have data for the fields you are requesting. How many tickers are we talking here?

Comment: They are all the same time, the problem is sometimes I am able to query all of them, sometimes it only returns part of the dataframe. I am only querying 25 tickers for 10 fields each, not like a lot

Comment: Perhaps try setting `timeout=1000` (or some number) on the `bdp` call and see if that helps? https://xbbg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/